# Java Server to handle HTTP GET/POST and receive & respond in JSON

Tags: java, http, post, get, spark-java

I want to write a code in Java which will act as sever for my angular front end(hosted on another server, npm). I need to receive the request, take values from the JSON sent and return a JSON.
I have looked into [sparkJava](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html). It looks perfect for me because I need to handle multiple requests like (/authentication, /records, /user/Details etc).
The problem I am having with Spark is that it is not able to receive request from another server. It works fine if front end is also hosted inside it.

Comment: Does java servlet suffice for your requirement?

Comment: Spark is that it is not able to receive request from another server? Not sure I understand. SparkJava is a singleton wrapper around JettyWebServer.
Please expand your question so it can be answered.

Comment: @domfarr..My front end is running on another server (npm). I tried sending request to my route in sparkjava but I get cross origin error. I have put in headers for response to allow cross origin and all HTTP methods but still it gives the same error.

Comment: please add the error to the question.

Comment: Use a web server like httpd or nginx to serve your front end and route requests to your back end. I have no experience with nginx but using httpd you can use mod proxy to hide your back end. That way you can use the same domain for your restful calls.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable a SparkJava application to receive external requests, you have to enable CORS. Add the following snippet before any route/filter.

```
        options("/*",
            (request, response) -> {

                String accessControlRequestHeaders = request
                        .headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
                if (accessControlRequestHeaders != null) {
                    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                            accessControlRequestHeaders);
                }

                String accessControlRequestMethod = request
                        .headers("Access-Control-Request-Method");
                if (accessControlRequestMethod != null) {
                    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                            accessControlRequestMethod);
                }

                return "OK";
            });
```

On client side (angularjs), do the following

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```